# How to trigger onClickListener for HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

The question explains everything I want.

HorizontalScrollView seems to be the only widget for which setOnClickListener() does'nt trigger.

NOTE: I can't use onTouch event because on every touch it is **triggered 4-5** times.

I also **can't use onTouch on its parent** view because parent view has many buttons with different functionality.

---

**The following description is not important:**

But still, these are the existing links I've searched(none helped):

[horizontalscrollview onclicklistener doesn't get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395830/horizontalscrollview-onclicklistener-doesnt-get-called)

[How to implement on click listener for horizontalscrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256019/how-to-implement-on-click-listener-for-horizontalscrollview)

[Click event of HorizontalScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155181/click-event-of-horizontalscrollview)

[Android click event of items in HorizontalScrollView not respond after scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649078/android-click-event-of-items-in-horizontalscrollview-not-respond-after-scroll)

These are the links which I posted(none got answered completely):

[Insert views in HorizontalScrollView programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827608/insert-views-in-horizontalscrollview-programatically?noredirect=1#comment33036423_21827608)

[One of the ImageButton not clicking & make HorizontalScrollView clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821206/one-of-the-imagebutton-not-clicking-make-horizontalscrollview-clickable/21821386?noredirect=1#comment33026161_21821386)

I asked multiple questions in these links, 1 of which was "onClickListener for HorizontalScrollView". That part of my question was never answered.

Hence an all exclusive question.

Comment: Could you ask your question? It's only asked in the title and I would like to see more details without having to open multiple links.

Comment: @Stan: The description is just useless....I just want code to trigger the onCilckEvent

Comment: Do you want the listener to be triggered when you click anywhere in a scroll view, or when you click on a specific object/objects inside that scrollView?

Comment: anywhere...on click I'm inserting view to HSV...so anywhere

Comment: Plz have a look at the following links: [Gallery-like HorizontalScrollView](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html) [Horizontal Scroll View](http://androiddreamers.blogspot.in/2012/09/horizontal-scroll-view-example.html) [ScrollableTabHost](https://code.google.com/p/mobyfactory-uiwidgets-android/) Let me know if u r facing any problem...

Comment: No, these are just different examples.. Can you please make an xml with HorizontalScrollView & see if you can trigger the onClickEvent

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I came up with two ways of doing it.

The simpler (but less ideal) one:

```
    HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Do stuff
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This will get called only once when you click, drag or whatever you do with your finger. However, it will also react to all kinds of gestures, so if you want to detect only tap/click events, you need to further investigate the "event" object and filter out events you don't need. This may be more work than you would like, so you should better use a GestureDetector to do it for you.

This leads to method 2:

```
    HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this, new OnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            // Do stuff.
            return false;
        }

        // Note that there are more methods which will appear here 
        // (which you probably don't need).
    });


    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I use method 2 and import "GestureDetector", the whole thing goes red with a --------- line on the GestureDetector . is GestureDetector gone ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it happened to me now and I came here for solution, but in my case it was just easier to listen to onClick to its child view instead...